# algorithmic complexity of classification algorithms/artificial neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, complexity-theory, decision-tree

the algorithmic complexity of binary trees is O(n), with n being the height of the tree. But are there any resources listing the complexity of methods for selecting the best tree? e.g. Boosted Regression Trees, CART or C4.5 (even MARS)

Also, I am not familiar with Artificial Neural Networks, but some references seem to point to specific ANN implementations being NP-complete: http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BR93.pdf, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.7.8997.

Does anybody know to what extent is it a general result?

Comment: I think that binary trees have O(log n) lookup if they are balanced, O(n) in the worst case. For neural networks it is just the forward pass and depends on your network architecture. So it is difficult to find a bound here- however you can try approximate it as k-matrix multiplications where k is the number of layers in your net.

Comment: Which operation of a binary tree are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasJungblut, you are right about binary tree lookup. Lookup is the operation I was referring to. Nevertheless, the core of the question is the other part, if there is a known algorithmic complexity of common tree construction methods